# Union of two vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone tell me how to union two vector spaces, it might be simple question but I forgot how to do that.

Lets say I was given two vector spaces $W$ and $U$:

$$W =  \operatorname{span}\{ (1,2), (1,1) \}$$
$$U = \operatorname{span}\{ (3,4), (2,2) \}$$

What is $W \cup U$?

Comment: What makes you believe there exists a simpler description than $W \cup U$? Note that a union of two subspaces is never a vector space unless one is contained in the other.

Comment: @alexprovost but how do I find $W \cup U$?

Comment: Hmm, in this case I believe $W=U=\mathbb R^2$, so their union is just $\mathbb R^2$ again. The pairs of vectors used to generate the spans are just different bases for the same space, right? Maybe you meant to use different 2-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$ instead?

Comment: @MPW But what it the procedure to find the union of two vector spaces?

Comment: @MPW Yes, I my question is more general then your answer

Comment: @LiziPizi I'm not sure what you mean by "find": an element in $W \cup U$ is a vector that belongs to $W$ or $U$.

Comment: @alexprovost yes but how do you write the set? "$W \cup U = \{ ..... \}$"

Comment: Think about a similar but lower-dimensional problem. Consider two distinct lines $W$ and $U$ through the origin in the plane. How do you "find" their union? It's just the union of the pair of lines, something roughly X-shaped. There isn't a simpler description of it. It isn't the span of anything because is isn't a vector subspace. It is, however, "star-shaped". Say, even the union of the x-axis and the y-axis. How would you write that?

Comment: @MPW I get that but how do you write the set?

Comment: @LiziPizi Assuming $W,U$ are subspaces of $V$: $W \cup U = \{ v \in V \mid v \in W \text{ or } v \in U\}$. Note that the vector space structure plays no role at all.

Comment: Many ways. One is $\{(x,y): x=0 \textrm{ or } y=0\}$. Another is $\{v:v\in W\ \textrm{ or } v\in U\}$.

Comment: @alexprovost it's the definition of the set, but can you take the example from my original question and write the set on it?

Comment: @MPW can you take the example I gave in my original question and write the set?

Comment: @LiziPizi Just replace $W$ and $U$ by whatever concrete subspace you want.

Comment: @Alexprovost is there a way to write it as a span of something?

Comment: @LiziPizi In this case yes, because both subspaces are contained in each other. In general no, because the union is not a vector space unless one subspace is contained in the other.

Comment: @alexprovost but if two vector spaces are contained in each other then the set is not just equal to the bigger vector space?

Comment: @LiziPizi Yes, here $U = W = V = \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @alexprovost thanks

Comment: $W+V$ is a subspace containing both $W$ and $V$.

Comment: The union is a vector space IFF one is contained in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are both subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then in fact $U = W = \mathbb{R}^2$, so $W \cup U = \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Can I get to something like this? $W \cup U = span \{ ...... \}$

Comment: @LiziPizi $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the span of your favorite pair of linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a union of two sets A and B is all the elements that belong to either A or B
In your case W∪U = span{(1,2),(1,1), (3,4),(2,2)} =span{(1,1), (3,4)}. Because some vectors are linear dependent. (note: thats as I rememver it. I will double check it in a while).

**Edit**
The above answer is wrong. The sum of subspaces is found there. The correct thing is the definition of the union. Another useful fact is that union may or may not be the vector space itself. In this case vectors virtually define the same Linear spaces and W∪U = W∪W = W = $ R^2 $

Comment: I do not think that is true to do what you did, you took their basis and put it in one span. This is $U + W$ what you did there

Comment: That belong to *either $A$ or $B$*.

Comment: Yes, you right - I have found the sum of the two subspaces of $ R^2 $. But i was not wrong with the definition of the union. Lets think geometrically. You have two planes. The union of subspaces is the all the vectors that belong to that planes, furthermore it  may not be the vector space. But what do we see in your case? W and U define the same plane ! So the answer is correct (however it was obtained from wrong considerations)

Comment: @ egreg definetely...